# List to Dictionary conversion using Linq

Tags: c#, list

Can somebody suggest me what Linq operator should I use to write an elegant code to convert List to Dictionary of list?
     Eg. I have a list of person (`List<Person>`) and I wanted to convert that to dictionary of list (like `Dictionary<string, List<Person>>` using the person's last name as a key. I needed that for quickly lookup the list of persons by the last name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a `Dictionary<string, List<Person>>` from `List<Person>`:

```
var dictionary = list
                   .GroupBy(p => p.LastName)
                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't what you asked for, but you can use Philip response for that :-)

```
var lookup = myList.ToLookup(p => p.Surname);
```

This will create an `ILookup<string, Person>` that is something very similar to what you wanted (you won't have a `Dictionary<string, List<Person>>` but something more similar to a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Person>>` and and the `ILookup` is readonly)

Comment: It won't if there are duplicate surnames

Comment: This is probably a better answer than mine for Daniel's purpose, now.

Comment: @Philip the read-onliness is quite often a show-stopper (as it's the fact that you have an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IList`). Different solutions for different problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use as follows.

```
foreach(var item in MyList)
 {  
   if(!myDictionary.Keys.Contains(item))
     myDictionary.Add(item,item.value);
 }
```